# How to search sphinx for fetching records with ID?

Tags: php, sphinx

I am using Sphinx search in my PHP project. I need to find an record from Sphinx index with ID. I have ID , just want to query Sphinx index for particular record rather than querying Database directly.

**My Scenario :**

I have list of tags in sql table and list of Jokes in another table. I have an join table for both called "jokes_tags" which has both of its id. Now I need to fetch all the jokes for particular tags.

**My Index :**

I am indexing the Jokes table with following Settings.

```
sql_query = SELECT entry_id, entry, picture_url,tags,date_added FROM jokes
```

**My Current flow :**

Currently I am trying to find whether the very exact tag (mean , if tag is 'funny jokes' I don't want matches like 'funny jokes meme') is available or not , if its available then, I am taking its ID and searching through "jokes_tags" for associating jokes id. Now I have Jokes IDs and want all the jokes from sphinx index.

What I am doing is right?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to include the 'joke_tags' data in the sphinx index; so you can get a list of jokes, by just using the tag_id in a query. A MVA is perfect for this....

```
sql_attr_multi = uint tag_id from query; SELECT joke_id,tag_id FROM jokes_tags ORDER BY joke_id
```

Then can just do

```
$cl->setFilter('tag_id',array($tag_id));
```

using the tag_id you looked up in your tags table :)